# Добавить условие в foreach

Tags: php, joomla, gtk2

Есть код который обрабатывает массив с элементами

```
<?php foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item): ?>
    <div class="category_item_container">
        <?php $this->item = $item;
              echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

В него нужно добваить условие `$this->item->created_by == JFactory::getUser()->id` , чтобы выводились только те элементы, которые были созданы авторизированным пользователем.

Я попыталась сделать разными способами, в том числе так :

```
<?php 
  foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item): 
    $this->item = $item; 
    if ($this->item->created_by == JFactory::getUser()->id){ 
    continue; 
    } 
   echo $this->loadTemplate('item'); 
  endforeach; 
?>
```

Однако все равно выводятся все элементы массива. Подскажите как нужно сделать, чтобы выводились только те элементы, которые были созданы авторизированным пользователем.

Comment: может надо именно `!==` а не `==` ?

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема заключается в том, что тогда у меня остаются пустые страницы пагинации. Так как сделала я изначально все работает. Но результаты выводятся на последней страницы. Таким образом я имею 4 пустые страницы.

Comment: Тогда наверное проблема в самом запросе.

Comment: Значит надо изначально правильный запрос в БД делать на получение данных в соответствии с айдишником пльзователя, чтобы в `primary` были только записи для определённого пользователя

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  foreach ($this->primary as $key => $item): 
    if ($item->created_by !== JFactory::getUser()->id) { 
      continue; 
    } 
    echo $this->loadTemplate('item'); 
  endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема заключается в том, что тогда у меня остаются пустые страницы пагинации.  Таким образом я имею 4 пустые страницы. Я также пыталась отфильтровать массив, но все равно пустые страницы пагинации

Comment: Выше уже ответили в комментариях, что нужно добавлять проверку на соответствие ID в запрос к базе, чтобы получить сразу релевантные данные

Comment: по другому никак? нельзя отфильтровать массив? Ведь айди создателя элемента отображается. айди текущего пользователя также можно получить. с формированием запроса в базу данных я боюсь не справлюсь

Comment: @Anna у вас пагинация формируется на основе выборке из БД. Так как жто взаимосвязанные вещи, то вам либо надо делать нормальную выборку (и не ясно а в чём сложности этого сделать), либо до кучи править объект пагинации под ваш цикл

Comment: @Anna править пагинацию будет сложнее, чем подправить сам запрос к базе

Comment: Я поняла. Благодарю, спасибо! Дело в том, что я зашла в models чтобы разобраться в каком месте осуществялется выборка для материалов и разобраться не получилсось

Answer (score 0):

Если JFactory::getUser()->id - это ИД авторизованного пользователя.

Почему бы тогда так не написать?

```
<?php
    foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item):
        $this->item = $item;
        if ($this->item->created_by == JFactory::getUser()->id){
            echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
        }
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: благодарю, да это работает, но получаются пустые страницы пагинации. в этом проблема. как удалить их не знаю

Comment: В этом проблема, поэтому я подумала, что что то делаю не так. Мне уже сказали что нужно менять запрос к БД ;(